# Reading text file from a parameter

Tags: java, parameters, text-files

The code I want to read from is called  *"textfile.txt"*,    now how do I pass this file as an argument in a parameter?

Pseudo code:

```
 readsomething(textfile);

 void readsomething(String reading) {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(reading));
 bla bla bla
 bla bla bla

 }
```

I have tried several variations of the above code, every time I get an error saying identifier is requires for readsomething(textfile);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
readsomething(textfile);
```

i am assuming that textfile parameter is a String (path to the file like "C:/abcfile.txt").

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(reading));
String line;
while((line=input.nextLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

refer to [Scanner API](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html&ei=Kg2ZUOT2BKeJ4gSdmoF4&usg=AFQjCNG01GOX5PM_0Cqkqh_uVqBbjVB-NA&sig2=LCuNubwQ5sNePVbsHx8dXw)

Comment: in readsomething(); do I put textfile.txt or just the filename?

Answer (score 0):

If You are using GUI, You can use [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) is an Example You can Refer to.

The file, you get from `JFileChooser` can be passed as an parameter for your function